# Horizontol Scrolling View in Android

Tags: android, scroller

I want to create a Horizontol Scrolling View in Android. The view would be a combination of images and text scrolling horizontally and I should be able to dynamically modify the content(text and images) in the Scroller

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

add HorizontalScroolView in the scrollview it will scroll in both directions.

```
ScrollView
  HorizontalScrollView
     ImageView
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps also have a look at the [Gallery element](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'd like something like ListView, but in horizontal orientation.

I'd make this to extend [AbsListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html), which is made to display dynamic lists.

Ideally if you'd copy ListView source and switch it to horizontal mode, but this is very complicated and long class, so look for easier options.

Try using [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) with just one row, stored in a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). Feed it with a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html), provide Views for your cells and setup content to display.

I didn't try this, but it seems like easy solution. Assuming that number of items will not be large, because there won't be optimizations available in ListView class.